# Applying attrs.frozen in metaclass removes Python type annotations

Tags: python, attr, metaclass

I try to apply `attrs.frozen` to all inheriting classes.
To do that I used a metaclass:

```
class MetaKlass(type):

    def __new__(mcs, name: str, bases: tuple[type, ...], attrs: dict[str, Any]):
        new = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        if TYPE_CHECKING or '__attrs_attrs__' not in attrs:
            return frozen(new)
        return new


class Klass(metaclass=MetaKlass):
    attribute: int
```

This code does not produce proper type hinting in VSCode, even though `Klass.__init__.__annotations__` contains `{'return': None, 'attribute': int}` as expected.

Is there a way to inform type checker that the metaclass produces the same result as

```
@frozen
class Klass:
    attribute: int
```

Comment: It sounds like VSCode is just confused by the addition of the Metaclass. Type hinting in Python is quite fragile in my experience, since it's relying on intelligent third-party tools to understand code that may do stuff like this at runtime.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say *fragile*, so much as the metaclass is making a dynamic (runtime) change to something that tools like `mypy` use statically (during source-code analysis).

Comment: `Klass.__init__` doesn't exist in the source code, let alone `Klass.__init__.__annotations__`; `frozen` adds it all at runtime. (Just because it's under `if TYPE_CHECKING` doesn't mean a type-checker actually *executes* `frozen`, or that it knows what `frozen` does. It only knows the *type* of the value returned by `frozen`, and that type doesn't include the contents of any new objects like `Klass.__init__.__annotations__`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static type checking code does not run the code. That is why it is called "static". As such, any metaclass code is not executed at all: no tool "emulate" what a metaclass would do: they just check the plain character arrangement in a class statement and its block + evaluate in an emulation like way, whatever code is present in the annotations themselves (inside the annotations). Although annotations have to be syntactic valid Python, and they are actually run when running the code, the type checking code does not do that. (in most tools. there may be a non-mainstream type checking tool that will actually check things at runtime)

All this means your `if TYPE_CHECKING` statement inside the metaclass' `__new__` method is never executed.